# Pressing Escape does not function in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, keypress

My target is to escape/remove the enlarged book screen from the page by pressing "Escape" key. The following are my code:

```
driver.get("http://www.packtpub.com/selenium-webdriver-practical-guide/book");
WebElement cookieClose = driver.findElement(By.id("cookie-close"));
if(cookieClose.isDisplayed()){
cookieClose.click();
}
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.bookimage")).click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
```

But the book image is not disappeared after pressing "Escape" key with WebDriver. (It is disappeared by pressing Escape key manually)

Answer (score 3):

The following 2 ways could work:

1. Getting the element locator of enlarged book image -> Send Escape to the element.

   WebElement bookImg = driver.findElement(By.id("hoverNav"));
   bookImg.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
2. You can press Escape key by Java Robot class as below:

   import java.awt.Robot;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

   Robot r = new Robot();
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Answer (score 0):

From selenium javadoc:
`public Actions sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
Sends keys to the active element.` 
Maybe you should use `keyDown(Keys theKey)` and `keyUp(Keys theKey)`

Comment: With scape Button the following error appears java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.

Answer (score 0):

Rather hit Escape on body of the page using the following code:

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

OR, You can use the following code to do the same thing:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

Now, you will see image disappeared.

Comment: Your concept is right. Element in which the book image is shown should be identified and operate Escape on that works well

Comment: Most probably, coding mechanism is different. In my case, image is displayed on a div. what about your case?

Comment: In the code above I mentioned, tag name `body` is of entire page, not for the image.

Comment: Yes, I have understood it was tag name body, not for the image. But, unfortunately in my case it did not work.